# How to put data into nested array and bind it to HTML Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have initialized array of objects and pushed another empty array inside it, I want this nested array to be updated right after getting data from an API. I am getting data in console but there is nothing happening at HTML side. I think this is because when I push empty array HTML is initialized as empty and when data is updated it is not binding data from nested Array.

I have tried it like this:

```
var dummy_data = { 
nested_array: ko.observableArray()
};
function IndexViewModel()
{
 var self = this;
 self.main_array = ko.observableArray([]);
};
// I want to push at start, because there are so many API calls and I don't 
// want user to wait until all data is loaded.
globalpointer.main_array.push(dummy_data);
fetch("/SomeRoute").then(x => {
        x.json().then(b => {
      dummy_data.nested_array = b;
   });
});
var globalpointer = new IndexViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(globalpointer);
```

HTML is:

```
 <!-- ko foreach:main_array() -->
   <!-- ko foreach:nested_array() -->
  <div data-bind='text:name'>

  </div>
   <!-- /ko -->
 <!-- /ko -->
```

I am expecting to get `name` in HTML, but I got nothing! Although I can see it in console when I write:

```
globalpointer.main_array()[0].nested_array
```

It displays all the info in `nested_array`.

Comment: `dummy_data.nested_arra(b);`  did u try this. `=` voilates 2 way binding data stays in object it wont bind to view.

Comment: Tried but didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replaces the observable array in `nested_array` with the parsed result of `json()`, which is not an observable array:

```js
 x.json().then(b => {
    dummy_data.nested_array = b;
 })
```

Assuming that your `fetch` result parses to an array, then you would want to do this:

```js
 x.json().then(b => {
    dummy_data.nested_array(b);
 })
```